# For a STV voting program in python, how to store voting scores from a text file into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

The text file below shows the voting preferences for 5 candidates. There are 4 ballots in the vote. The first number of each ballot is Candidate A, the second is Candidate B and so on... The number 1 means that that candidate was the first choice of the voter, and so on until the third preference. There are no fourth or fifth preferences so zeros are used. How would I put these scores in a 2-dimensional array in python so that it outputs a list of each candidate's score such as:

A (1, 2, 3, 0)
B (2, 3, 1, 2)
C (3, 1, 0, 0)
D (0, 0, 0, 3)
E (0, 0, 2, 1)

1, 2, 3, 0, 0

2, 3, 1, 0, 0

3, 1, 0, 0, 2

0, 2, 0, 3, 1

Comment: What wrong with `[[], ...]`?

Answer (score 0):

## Change format

The first option is to change the textfile format. From your question it looks like the A, B, C, ... are not important. If you delete these, the program is a lot easier, for example if you store the votes as JSON or just a 2-dimensional array itself.

## Program as is

If changing the format is no option due to other parts of you program this may work:

```
content = ""
votes = [[] for i in range(number_of_candidates)]

with open("file.txt", "r") as text:
    content = text.read()

while content.find('(') != -1:
    start = content.find('(')
    end = content.find(')')

    current_votings = content[start + 1 : end]
    content = content[end + 1:]
    
    j = 0
    for vote in current_votings.replace(',', ''):
        votes[j].append(int(vote))
        j += 1
```

Hope this helps.